# Counting the number of exceptions happening in catch block

Tags: java, atomic, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to collect all the counts of exception happening and the name of exception in a `ConcurrentHashMap` so that I should be aware of how many times this exception has occurred.

So in my catch block I have map that will keep on adding the name of exception and there total count occurrence.

Below is my code `which I have modified to always throw SQL Exception` everytime for the testing purpose so that I can see the count of exception is accurate or not.

So certain scenario-

1) If I am choosing number of threads as `10` and number of tasks as `50`, then in that map, I can see 500 exception for that particular String

2)But If I am choosing number of threads as `40` and number of tasks as `500` then I am not seeing `20000` exceptions in that map, it shows around `19000`.

My question is why? What wrong I am doing here?

```
class Task implements Runnable {

     public static final AtomicInteger counter_exception = new AtomicInteger(0);
     public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

     @Override
     public void run() {

     try {

          //Making a db connection and then executing the SQL-

         } catch (SQLException e) {
               exceptionMap.put(e.getCause().toString(), counter_exception.incrementAndGet());
          } catch (Exception e) {

          }
     }

    }
```

**Updated:**

If I have something like this- I am getting `Null Pointer Exception` for 40 threads and 4000 taks. Why?

```
catch (SQLException e) {

synchronized(this) {
                   exceptionMap.put(e.getCause().toString(), counter_exception.incrementAndGet());
}              
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this map? If an exception with a given cause happens only once, but is the 100th exception, it will have the value 100. How is that helpful?

Comment: We are going to do Load and Performance Testing on our new Database. So for that I have written a Multithreaded code. So we will be running the same program on lots of thread and will be putting load on the database. So if at any point database got break, so I needed to know what exceptions it is throwing and how many times so that we can go and talk with the respective vendor about this problem, so that is the reason I am doing all this. And it's a new database in the market that we are about to use.

Comment: I understand that. But since you use a single counter for all your exceptions, you wan't be able to know how many times an exception has been thrown. You need one counter per exception cause.

Comment: Yeah. That thing I can fix for sure. I forgot that totally. Thanks for reminding me. But there is any way apart from this Lock Solution you are suggesting in the below answer?

Comment: For the NPE: We know the `exception` isn't null. We know `this` isn't null. Why not rewrite the code so it tells you if `e.getCause()` returns null, if `counter_exception` is null or if `exceptionMap` is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this is happening:

Task 1-500: Catch exceptions, prepare to call `exceptionMap.put`, get a number from `counter_exception.incrementAndGet()` that is passed to said method

Task 500: Has number 500 from the atomic integer counter, is scheduled so its `exceptionMap.put` runs first

Task 1: Has number 1 from the atomic integer counter, is scheduled so its `exceptionMap.put` runs last

Now even though the counter is 500 and we had 500 exceptions, the exception message gets associated with 1 because that was executed the most recently.

Comment: +1: incrementing the counter is atomic. Putting a new value in the map is atomic. But doing both without synchronization is not atomic.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So what is the best way to avoid this problem? Any thoughts how should I avoid this problem?

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks for making me more clear. Any thoughts of fixing this problem?

Comment: Make these two operations atomic by putting them into a synchronized block.

Comment: Any other solution apart from this Lock based?

Comment: No. But why would it be a problem? I think you're optimizing prematurely. Exceptions should be rare. And acquiring a lock will be several orders of magnitude faster than executing a SQL query. So you'd better optimize the SQL queries and the IO, instead of optimizing the increment of an in-memory counter.

Comment: Yeah make sense now. I guess you are right. I updated the question with the way you are suggesting me to do. Let me know if that thing is not right. Or I missed any useful information.

Comment: And after synchronizing like that, I started getting NullPointerException after running for few seconds if I ran the same program for `40` threads and `4000` number of tasks. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Can't say unless you show us code and the line on which it's dereferencing null.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as being the wrong approach.

If you are getting exceptions in your application under load, you should be finding the cause (or causes) of those exceptions ... and FIXING them.

Counting the exceptions doesn't help.  In fact, that you are likely to make the problem worse by:

- making it hard to understand your code to the extra complexity you are adding,
- causing the symptoms to change, making it harder to identify the bugs that cause them, and
- introducing NEW bugs due to mistakes in the way that you are counting the exceptions.

---

OK, so what can you do to make the problems easier to find?

- Review your codebase to make sure that you are not *squashing* exceptions.
- Look for exception handlers that don't log the exception.
- Look for overly broad exception handlers; e.g. for `Exception` or `RuntimeException` or `Throwable`.
- Look for exception handlers that catch exceptions too soon.  If you have an unexpected exception, the best thing you can do is to allow it to propagate "to the top" and kill the application or (for a web container) the current request.  Trying to do a more specific recover is a bad idea ... 'cos your code doesn't know what the exception means or what caused it.
- Finally, make sure that all threads have an uncaught exception handler ... so that any uncaught exceptions are at least logged.

If you have exceptions appearing when the application is under load (especially bizarre ones) the chances are that you've got data structures / objects / variables that are shared by two or more threads and that are not properly synchronized.  I recommend that you do a code review of your codebase *looking* for this kind of problem.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at your updated code, the most likely cause of your NPE's is that `e.getCause()` is returning `null`; i.e. some of your exceptions don't have a chained "cause" exception!  That should be trivial to deal with; i.e. test the value returned by `e.getCause()`.

Note that since you are using `ConcurrentHashMap`, you cannot use `null` as a key.  This is expressly forbidden - see the javadoc.

Another possible cause is incorrect synchronization.

```
synchronized(this) {
    exceptionMap.put(e.getCause().toString(), 
                     counter_exception.incrementAndGet());
}
```

The problem is that you are synchronizing on `this`, and other threads executing the same code will have a different `this` ... so you won't synchronize with them.

However, I'm pretty sure that you don't actually *need* to synchronize with other threads here because:

- the static variables are initialized during class initialization and (presumably) not assigned to after that, and
- the method calls you are making on the shared objects are thread-safe.

I would declare `exceptionMap` to be `final`, and get rid of the `synchronized` block.

If you really do need to synchronize, you should be synchronizing on one of those two static objects, or maybe on `Task.class`.

Comment: Yeah I agree Stephen, I am not only counting the exceptions, I am also logging all those exception. In my question, I have removed those logging part just to make it more clear..