# Counting the Exception and Logging it in the same method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am tring to `count` the number of `exceptions` happening and also log those `exceptions` as well. So what I did is, I created one method `addException` in which I am counting all the exceptions.

`addException` method will accepts two parameters, `one is the String`, and other is the `boolean flag` which means whether we want to terminate the program or not because of any exceptions. Meaning, if that flag is true, then I need to terminate the program whenever there are any exceptions.

So if you take a look into my below `catch` block, I have `addException` method call for counting the exceptions and below that method call I am logging the exceptions as well.

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
    LOG.error("Threw a ClassNotFoundException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    addException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString(), Read.flagTerminate);
    //DAMN! I'm not....
    LOG.error("Threw a SQLException while making connection to database in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
}


/**
 * A simple method that will add the count of exceptions and name of
 * exception to a map
 * 
 * @param cause
 * @param flagTerminate 
 */
private static void addException(String cause, boolean flagTerminate) {
    AtomicInteger count = exceptionMap.get(cause);
    if (count == null) {
        count = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger curCount = exceptionMap.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
        if (curCount != null) {
            count = curCount;
        }
    }
    count.incrementAndGet();

    if(flagTerminate) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am looking for is-

Is there any more cleaner way of doing the same thing? Meaning right now I am counting the exceptions in a method and then printing out the exceptions in the next line inside the catch block.

Is it possible to do the both of the things in the same `addException` method? And if the flag is true to terminate the program, then terminate the program with the proper logging as well.

What could be the best way to re write `addException method` to do this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: How is this different from your other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783266/counting-the-number-of-exceptions-happening-in-catch-block?

Comment: We are working on same project. I didn't knew he already posted that out. Sorry about that. Any way to remove this question then? He gave me the description and ask me to take some help.

Comment: You can delete this question, and update the other one with any details required. I assume you all are sharing an account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any more cleaner way of doing the same thing? Meaning right
>   now I am counting the exceptions in a method and then printing out the
>   exceptions in the next line inside the catch block.
>
> Is it possible to do the both of the things in the same addException
>   method? And if the flag is true to terminate the program, then
>   terminate the program with the proper logging as well.

Yes, instead of passing String cause to the `addException` method, you could pass the exception itself and the flag if you want. Or even do the complete catching inside the `addException` method like:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e) {
    addException(e, Read.flagTerminate);
}
```

or

```
catch (Exception e) {
    addException(e, Read.flagTerminate);
}
```

or even:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    addException(e, Read.flagTerminate, "Threw a ClassNotFoundException in "); //An the addException method logs the message passed.    
} catch (SQLException e) {
    addException(e, Read.flagTerminate, "Threw a SQLException while making connection to database in ");
}
```

You could have a map in the class that have stored which exceptions should stop execution and which shouldn't, with that you will only need an `addException(Exception e)` method.

You could even create a properties file that have a localized message for each type of exception and log that message by default.

You can also check the link suggested by @perception:

[Counting the number of exceptions happening in catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783266/counting-the-number-of-exceptions-happening-in-catch-block)